# BackboneJS - Fetch data from PHP file and display in View

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, backbone.js

I'm fetching some data from my MySQL database with a php file and now I want to display this data in my View by passing it through a Model with the json_encode method. So far I created a Router, a Model, a Collection (is it necessary?) and a View. When i console.log the collection in my View, I can see that the data is actually there but my View shows nothing. When i console.log the Model I get the "undefined" message. So it seems that the Model is not instantiated, but I dont really know how to solve it. I use RequireJS and the HandlebarsJS for HTML templating purpose.

So here is my Router.

```
define(['backbone',
       'views/firstpage',
       'views/secondpage',
       'views/thirdpage',
       'collections/BandCollection']),
function( Backbone,FirstpageView, SecondpageView, ThirdpageView,BandCollection ) {
   var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'index',
            'firstpage' : 'firstpage',
            'secondpage' : 'secondpage',
            'thirdpage' : 'thirdpage'
          },
        initialize: function () {
           this.bandCollection = new BandCollection();

           this.bandCollection.fetch({
              error: function () {
              console.log("error!!"); 
            },
            success: function (collection) {
            console.log("no error"); 
          }
   });
},

        thirdpage: function() {
            var thirdpageView = new ThirdpageView({ el:'#topContent', collection:this.bandCollection}).render();

        },

    });

    return Router;
    }
 );
```

My Model looks like this:

```
define([
"jquery",
"backbone"
],

function($, Backbone) {
var BandModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "../metal/db/bands.php",

    defaults: {
        "id": '',
        "band": '',
        "label": ''
    }
});

return BandModel;
});
```

My Collection:

```
define([
"backbone",
"models/BandModel"
],

function(Backbone, BandModel) {
var BandCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: BandModel,
    url: "../metal/db/bands.php"
});

return BandCollection;
});
```

My HTML template:

```
<div>
   <p><%= id %></p>
   <p><%= band %></p>
   <p><%= label %></p>
</div>
```

And My View looks like this:

```
define(['backbone','handlebars', 'text!templates/Thirdpage.html'],

    function(Backbone,Handlebars, Template) {


        'use strict';

        var ThirdpageView = Backbone.View.extend({

            template: Handlebars.compile(Template),

            initialize: function () {
                _.bindAll(this, 'render');
                this.render();
            },

            render: function() {
                console.log(this.collection);
                this.$el.html(this.template(this.collection.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }

        });

        return ThirdpageView;

    }
);
```

As said before, the console.log(this.collection) tells me that the data is available..

```
{length: 6, models: Array[6], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
```

but console.log(this.model) gives me "undefined" - and the View actually displays the HTML mentioned before and not the data, meaning it actually shows

```
<div>
<p><%= id %></p>
<p><%= band %></p>
<p><%= label %></p>
</div>
```

So, can anyone help me out? I'm out of ideas...

Comment: You are using Handlebars. Shouldn't your template be using `{{}}` instead of `<%= %>`?

Comment: @SandeepNayak I just tried with `{{}}`, but no result...

Comment: Try my answer below. We use `<%= %>` if we are using underscore.js to compile our templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your render() method in your view like this:

```
render: function() {
   var self = this;
   console.log(this.collection);
   self.collection.each(function(model){
        console.log(this.model);  // can view all models here
        self.$el.append(self.template({id:model.get('id'),band:model.get('band'),label:model.get('label')}));
   });

   return this;
}
```

Change your Template like this:

```
<div>
  <p>{{id}}</p>
  <p>{{band}}</p>
  <p>{{label}}></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, this gives me 2 errors: "Unexpected token :" on the view and "undefined is not a function" on my router, it refers to the "var thirdpageView = new ThirdpageView..."-line

Comment: OK i solved it! There was just a syntax error in your submitted answer: `self.$el.append(self.template({id:model.get('id'),band:model.get('band'),label:model.get('label')}));` - Thanks alot!!!

Comment: @SHT: oh Yes, edited my answer. Overlooked it while typing. Glad you could find it. Thanks!